# Create Dynamic List of Refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamically created list of React elements that's created by running a method in the render function:

```
surveyFileErrors.map((errorData, i) => {
 return arr.push(<FileErrorCard ref={} key={errorData.id} errorData={errorData} />);
}
```

and I'm trying to create a Ref for each element so that I can change the focus to an element with the up and down arrows. This is my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fileErrorList: [],
      activeList: null,
      activePage: 1,
    };
    this.errorRefs = [];
}
```

I'm trying to use the new React.createRefs() in React 16.3 but the example it gives shows that I need to use React.createRefs in the constructor which would execute before I even start creating the above list. This list is only created after an action retrieves the list of errors as well. I can provide more information, but I don't want to write too long of a post.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work, hope it helps:

```
const refObj = {};
surveyFileErrors.map((errorData, i) => {
     refObj[i] = React.createRef();
     return arr.push(<FileErrorCard ref={refObj[i]} key={errorData.id}
                     errorData={errorData} />);
    }
```